# Error: cannot find symbol for BufferReader

Tags: debugging

I have the following code:

```
import.java.io.*;
public class BasheminParkingLot
{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception
    {
        Stack parkinglot = new Stack();
        Stack alley= new Stack();
        File f = new File("bashemin.in");
        FileInputStream finstream = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader finreader = new InputStreamReader(finstream);
        BufferReader finput = new BufferReader(finreader);
        String line = finput.readLine();
        String plate = "";
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Bashemin Status");
        System.out.println();

        while(line!=null)
        {
            if(line.charAt(0)=='a')
            {
                plate = line.substring(1);
                System.out.println ("car" + plate + " arrived and parked");
                parkinglot.Push(plate);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and am getting the error:

BasheminParkingLot.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        BufferReader finput = new BufferReader(finreader);
        ^

I was wondering if anyone could help me debug this?? Thanks!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Accepting and up voting will motivate people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be `BufferReader`. It should be `BufferedReader`.

The following code will work:

```
import java.io.*;

class Stack {
    int x;

    void Push(String value) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}

public class BasheminParkingLot
{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
    {
        Stack parkinglot = new Stack();
        Stack alley= new Stack();
        File f = new File("bashemin.in");
        FileInputStream finstream = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader finreader = new InputStreamReader(finstream);
        BufferedReader finput = new BufferedReader(finreader);
        String line = finput.readLine();
        String plate = "";
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Bashemin Status");
        System.out.println();

        while(line!=null)
        {
            if(line.charAt(0)=='a')
            {
                plate = line.substring(1);
                System.out.println ("car" + plate + " arrived and parked");
                parkinglot.Push(plate);
            }
        }

    }
}
```